# Clicking doesn't open detail view in qUnit test (with ember-testing)

Tags: ember.js, qunit

I have a master/detail page that I am trying to test. There is a list of `things`, which, when you click renders the route for the `thing`.

The following test finds the `thing` to click, but doesn't seem to click it.

```
@exists = (selector) ->
  !!find(selector).length

...

test "things expand to show a detail view", 1, ->
   visit("/").then(->
     click(".things li:contains('Example Thing')")
   ).then ->
     ok(@exists("h2")) # a tag in the detail view

...

<ul class='things'>
  {{#each controller}}
    <li>{{#linkTo 'thing' this}}{{title}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}

...

<div class='thing'>
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
</div>
```

This raises with: `Failure/Error: Element h2 not found.` Does anybody know what I am missing/how to get this test to pass?

I am using teaspoon (formerly known as teabag) in the browser as a test runner, if that makes a difference. Should I be able to see the interaction happening as the test clicks around?

Comment: If I `visit` the page manually, it finds the `h2` fine.

Comment: what version of ember are you using? Do you have an integration helper that will build the app before each test is run? something like this https://github.com/toranb/ember-testing-example/blob/master/js/tests/integration_test_helper.js

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't click the `<li>` element, but the `<a>` element instead. 
The `linkTo` helper in handlebars generate an `<a>` tag in the DOM.

Something like `click(".things li:contains('Example Thing') a ")` should works.